# Improve datatable.js loading speed of large scale data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

Basically the code is working fine, it's just that when the data was getting more and more huge, the loading speed became very very slow.

Anyone can advise on how to improve the loading speed?

Below is my code:

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [0]
            }]
    });

});
</script>
```

Datatable:

```
<table class="list" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="first" width="1" style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').prop('checked', this.checked);"></td>
            <td class="left">Location ID</td>
            <td class="left">Location</td>
            <td class="left">Issued By</td>
            <td class="left">Supervise by Role</td>
            <td class="right">Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM location";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $data['locationname']; ?>">
                </td>
                <td class="left"><?php echo $data['lid']; ?></td>
                <td class="left"><?php echo $data['locationname']; ?></td>
                <td class="left"><?php echo $data['issuedby']; ?></td>
                <td class="left"><?php echo "Supervisor - " .  $data['locationname']; ?></td>
                <td class="right"> [ <a href="index.php?cmd=location&route=location&fn=view&lid=<?php echo $data['lid']; ?>">View</a> ] [ <a href="index.php?cmd=location&route=location&fn=edit&lid=<?php echo $data['lid']; ?>">Edit</a> ]</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Load data in chunks using AJAX ..

Comment: will that affect the sorting and pagination?

Comment: don't select it all at once, of course it'll be slow in time, thats bound to happen. its in the [docs](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/), read it and try to revise your code

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX to load data in chunks, if your data set is large.

Here is the link from which you can fetch information regarding adding a new row to the datatable:

http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

*As seen in the example datatable will handle the pagination and sorting itself.*